# How to carry out this kind of analysis in Relativity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, angular-momentum, mathematical-physics

In the paper [arxiv.org/abs/0801.0926](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0926) the authors propose the following simple system of particles in Newtonian mechanics. Four particles of same mass placed as follows

[image]

The $a(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ can be prescribed at will. The author assumes no external forces so that the momentum is conserved. The author then wants to find an equation for this $\phi$.

It turns out that conservation of angular momentum does the job. Momentum is conserved and it starts as zero, so that $L = 0$ should be kept along the evolution. One can then write $L$ in terms of $m,a(t),\theta(t)$ and $\phi$

$$L = 4\dot{\phi}(a^2+b^2)+4\dot{\theta}a^2=0$$

this in turn furnishes

$$\dot{\phi}=-\dot{\theta}\dfrac{a^2}{a^2+b^2},$$

which in turn gives $\Delta \phi$ after a sequence $a(t),\theta(t)$ of internal movements

$$\Delta \phi = -\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \dfrac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}d\theta. $$

I want to do the same in Relativity theory. Initially, Special Relativity.

Now, the way to deal with extended bodies in relativity theory is by means of Dixon's multipole theory as is well-known.

The issue is: Dixon's theory just give equations for (1) momentum of the body, (2) center of mass of the body and (3) angular momentum of the body.

If we follow the approach as above closely, the momentum is constant, the center of mass should be just one $t = t_0$ worldline, and then there's angular momentum. If we want to do the exact same analysis, things should follow from angular momentum.

But here angular momentum is

$$S^{\alpha\beta}=2\int_\Sigma (x^{[\alpha}-z^{[\alpha})T^{\beta]\gamma}d\Sigma_\gamma$$

with respect to some origin $z$. We should choose this $z$ as the center of mass.

Now, I have no idea how to compute this because I don't know what $T^{\mu\nu}$ is for this system. It should encode the $a(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, but I have no idea how.

Furthermore, it is not clear what is the analogue of $L = 0$ here.

So, how is this system correctly described in special relativity, and how can we perform the same analysis to find $\Delta \phi$?

Any help whatsoever is appreciated.

Comment: If you want capital $\phi$, use `\Phi` ($\Phi$) rather than `\phi`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build the energy-momentum tensor by hand. My first approach would be to use the form of the tensor for an [isolated particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Isolated_particle) and use linearity. 
$$T^{\mu\nu}(t,\vec{x}) = \sum_\textrm{p} E_p v^{(p)\alpha}(t)v^{(p)\beta}(t)\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_p(t)) $$
Then you might be able to include your constraints within the 4-velocities of each mass as needed. At the end you should be able to compute the angular momentum from the formula you wrote above.

Comment: So, expanding a bit: the center of mass moves uniformly, so we can work in its adapted coordinates. So we assume the origin to be the CoM, momentum is constant, so we assume $p^\mu$ to give the direction of the time axis. Each particle has velocity $\mathbf{v}(t)$ with respect to coordinate time $t$, so its four-velocity is $v^\mu = \gamma(1, \mathbf{v})$. I can work out then $\mathbf{v}(t)$ on each constant $t$ hyperplane in terms of the given parameters as in Newtonian mechanics, then workout the trajectories and thus build the EM tensor. Is that the point ?

Comment: Yeah that is my guess, choose the origin of coordinates you want, there is no need to make any reference to momentum conservation at the moment. At the end $\vec{v}(t)$ should only depend on angles and $\dot{a}$ and $b$. Time is still a variable of the energy-momentum tensor. At the end of the day you might have to deal with a differential equation that states the conservation of angular momentum, $\partial_\mu S^{\mu\nu}=0$, as in the Newtonian case.